# Laravel PHPUnit error mysql fulltext index

Tags: laravel, phpunit, full-text-search

Just got an error while running PHPUnit in Laravel after add FULLTEXT index

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "name": syntax error
```

After investigating, the error caused by migration that I've added

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddFulltextIndexToProductName extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE products ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_index(name)');
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement('DROP INDEX `fulltext_index`');
    }
}
```

If I remove that migration code, the test running gracefully

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: You have syntax error, can you please add more code to see why you getting this.

Comment: Hi @cike4ka I've updated the description Thanks

Comment: It's not correctly way. never write DB: statement on your migration file, migrations are space where you can create db tables, like `$table->sometype('table name')` , and if you want to manipulate with tables, like create, delete, edit . . . data i recommend to use controller, but code which you have written can also be implemented in your Models. I recommend to read laravel documentation for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually Laravel tests are using in memory sqlite database and this statement in your migration will not work. 
You can check how to create sqlite full text index here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-full-text-search/

Since Laravel doesn't support full text search out of the box I assume you have written custom function which probably also will not work in tests.

To overcome the issue you can:

- use mysql for test (not recommended since it is slow)
- use repositories pattern
- skip the migration when in tests (if you are not
  testing the search - you don't need it). You can check with
  `if(env('APP_ENV') === 'testing')`
- use laravel scout for search

Answer (score 0):

For conditional indexes, instead of checking the environment, I suggest checking the DB driver, e.g.:

```php
return new class () extends Migration {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('body');

            if (!$this->isSqlite()) {
                $table->fullText('body');
            }

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }

    private function isSqlite(): bool
    {
        return 'sqlite' === Schema::connection($this->getConnection())
                ->getConnection()
                ->getPdo()
                ->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME);
    }
};
```